# Very very high speed serial communication over serial port in C# with best perfomance and without any data lost

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication

I have a data losing problem over C# serial port in an sample app with very very high speed data receiving (up to 36000 byte per second in 2000 datapacks with 18 byte) from a micro controller board.

My baudrate is 1.000.000 and I use `DataReceived` event. And I have a simulator to generate data for main application test. I paired two COM port (COM1 -> COM2) with "Virtual Serial Port Driver" software.

After the datapacks have been received, they are saved to a `*.CSV` file with some data getting lost.

My first and important problem is the data loss.

My second problem is CPU usage performance in this case (up to 50% or 60%).

This is my simulator serialport config and data generator code:

```
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 1000000, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
serialPort.Open();
serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);

byte[] packet = new byte[] { 83, 84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 69, 78 };
ulong packetCount = 0;
while (packetCount < 600000);
{
    byte[] timeBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(packetCount);
    packet[2] = timeBytes[0]; 
    packet[3] = timeBytes[1]; 
    packet[4] = timeBytes[2]; 
    packet[5] = timeBytes[3];
    Write(packet);
    packetCount++;
}
```

In this code, packet has a header {83, 84} and footer {69, 78}

This is serial port config in my main application:

```
SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM2", 1000000, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
_serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
_serialPort.ReadBufferSize = 100;
```

This is the `dataReceived` event in my main application:

```
private void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int count = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
    byte[] receivedTemp = new byte[count];
    _serialPort.Read(receivedTemp, 0, count);
    _totalReceived.AddRange(receivedTemp);
    findPacket();
}
```

This is the `findPacket` function to find a packet using its header and footer:

```
int findPacket(int index = 0, bool headerFounded = false)
{
    while (index + 1 < _totalReceived.Count)
    {
        if (_totalReceived[index] == 83 && _totalReceived[index + 1] == 84)
        {
            int headerIndex = index;
            int packetLen = 14; 
            int footerIndex = findPacket(index + 2 + packetLen, true);
            if (footerIndex > -1 && (packetLen == 0 || (footerIndex == headerIndex + packetLen + 2)))
            {
                List<byte> data = totalReceived.GetRange(headerIndex + 2, footerIndex - (headerIndex + 2));
                totalReceived.RemoveRange(headerIndex, footerIndex + 2 - headerIndex);
                if (headerIndex > 0 && !headerFounded)
                    totalReceived.RemoveRange(0, headerIndex);

                calcPacket(data);
                continue;
            }
            else if (footerIndex != -1)
            { 
                 index++; 
                 continue; 
            }
            break;
        }

        if (headerFounded && totalReceived[index] == 69 && totalReceived[index + 1] == 78)
            return index;

        index++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Problem is: `findPacket` is very very busy when simulator data generator is started, and all of other async functions (like main UI and CSV writer and online chart drawer and ...) in my main app are not working and locked.

Comment: The code in finPacket is a little strange, You're calling the findPacket recursive. Flipping the headerFounded for searching for the footer? why not create a separate method for that?
I would probably do something like.  The packets are fixed length. Ones you have the header, the footer is always x bytes away. Just check the length of the received bytes. If the length is less than the packet length, try receiving more bytes until it's greater than the packet length. If you received more bytes than one packet, just blockcopy it to the start of the array. I cannot test it here.

Comment: In order to gain speed, you might want to decouple receiving and processing. That is: in the event handler, just enqueue the received data and have it processed on another thread, so processing will not be the bottleneck for receiving. It _may_ also simplify your algorithm on the way.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen the packet may sometimes be incomplete. there is a header without any footer in the received data. So, after finding the new header, I call the findPacket() recurring again so that if you find a new header without finding the previous footer, it will be okay. On the other hand, as you need to search the data received with a n order, I will pass the current header index to the subsequent recall of the findPacket() . And with it, in the second call findPacket(), a flag called headerFound is also passed to the findPacket() to prevent the error of finding a footer without header.

Comment: The packet should only be incomplete, when there are not enough bytes received. That's the advantage you have with fixed length. Just check the length and use the footer just as a check, instead of "searching" for it.

Comment: Handshake.None means "I can deal with data loss".  Clearly you can't, you don't have an error-correcting protocol, use Handshake.RequestToSend on both ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without using the recursive function. Recursive functions increase the resources used by the system. In this case, the number of calls may be excessive and cause a time error
you can do this:

```
  async void findPacket3()
    {
        byte[] header = new byte[] { 83, 84 };
        byte[] footer = new byte[] { 69, 78 };
        int maxLength = header.Length + footer.Length;

        int index = 0;
        int headerIndex = -1;
        int footerIndex = -1;
        while (!_canceltoken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(5);
            while (index < totalRecieved.Count)
            {
                if (index + (header.Length - 1) < totalRecieved.Count && totalRecieved[index] == header[0] && totalRecieved[index + 1] == header[1])
                {
                    headerIndex = index;
                    int packetLen = 0; // findPacketLen(index);
                    index += header.Length + packetLen;
                    continue;
                }
                if (headerIndex > -1 && index + (footer.Length - 1) < totalRecieved.Count && totalRecieved[index] == footer[0] && totalRecieved[index + 1] == footer[1])
                {
                    footerIndex = index;
                    List<byte> data = totalRecieved.GetRange(headerIndex + header.Length, footerIndex - (headerIndex + header.Length));
                    calcPacket(data);
                    headerIndex = -1;
                }
                index++;
            }
            if (footerIndex > -1)
            {
                totalRecieved.RemoveRange(0, footerIndex + footer.Length);
                footerIndex = -1;
                index = 0;
                headerIndex = -1;
            }
        }

    }
```

Also, in order to avoid data loss, it is better to set

```
_serialPort.ReadBufferSize = 4096;
```